# Joining data from multiple files using aggregate gives 'cyclic dependency error'-Mongoose/MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've 3 tables

```
1.User
_id:123
name
email

2.contact:
userId:123
hospitalId:321

3.Hospital:
_id:321
```

I need mongoose equivalent of below SQL query:

```
select *from user where _id in (select userId from contact where hospitalId = 321) 

Users.aggregate(
[
    { "$match": {
        "_id": { 
            "$in": db.contact.distinct("userid",{ "hospitalId": 321 })
        }
    }}
])
```

when I tried this I got cyclic dependency error.

Answer (score 0):

This will group users based on the hospitalId by joining data from two collections

```
db.hospital.aggregate([
{ $group: {  _id: "$_id"} }, 
{ $lookup: {  
from: 'contact',  
localField: '_id',  
foreignField: 'hospitalId',  
as: 'Details'
}}, 
{ $project: { 
'Details.hospitalId': 0, 
'Details._id': 0 }} 
])
```

The O/P is:

/* 1 */

```
{
    "_id" : 456,
    "Details" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : 890
        }
    ]
}
```

/* 2 */

```
{
    "_id" : 321,
    "Details" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : 123
        }, 
        {
            "userId" : 4657697
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: _id of user is mapped to userId of contact.Before that I need to get all those contacts having hospitald:321.So do you think the above query works in this context?

Comment: check my updated query and op. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: If you want to get all the users with hospitald:321, add a group stage to the query

Comment: Thanks Anban for trying but what I want is the list of users whose Id is in 'contact' where 'contact' has hospId=321.

Comment: @sreeyachowdary I've edited my answer that would group the users based on the hospitalId. Try and let me know the outcome

Comment: The query you gave is getting the details from 'contact' but what I want is the data like name and email from 'user' table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hospital.find({
    hospitalId: {
                 $eq: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.hospitalId)
                }
    }).then((hsptl)=>{
        let result = hsptl.map(a => a.pocId);
        User.find({
                _id: { $in:result }
        }).then((usr)=>{
             res.json(usr);
        });
    });
```

This is the expected solution